# What is a word that describes a random word presented in a conversation?

Tags: descriptive-grammar, figurative

For example, if two people are discussing cows & dairy farming & one person mentions carpet. Is there a word for this? Maybe a literary term?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I checked a bunch of answers that offered *non-sequitur*, and none of them were clear enough for me to vote to close this one as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

That’s known as a ***non sequitur***

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(literary_device)) says:

> A non sequitur (English pronunciation: /ˌnɒnˈsɛkwᵻtər/; Classical Latin: [noːn ˈsɛkᶣɪtʊr] "it does not follow") is a conversational and literary device, often used for comedic purposes. It is something said that, because of its apparent lack of meaning relative to what preceded it, seems absurd to the point of being humorous or confusing.

Comment: It is very easy to back-check for duplicates in this case.